Collision in slotted ALOHA if the stations have different distance
In slotted ALOHA, if 2 or more stations send the message at the same slot to the server, a collision will have occurred. However, If those stations have different distances to the server, the propagation will be different as well. So how to consider collision in this case?

The propagation delay is generally tiny compared to the slot time.  If two stations try to use the same slot, they will collide, regardless of any difference in propagation.
